# specify label's position to be above of the dropdown menu in html

Tags: html, dropdown

How can I specify the position of the label to be above the dropdown menu?

E.g.

```
<form action="/action_page.php">
  <label for="cars">Choose a car:</label>
  <select name="cars" id="cars">
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="opel">Opel</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
  </select>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Is there any style argument in `<label for="cars">Choose a car:</label>` that would place it above the menu?

Thank you!

Comment: It should already be above the input, I think you may need to explain what you mean in more detail or provide a functioning example of it not working.

Comment: @DBS. Thanks for your help. It's on the left side, not above. See https://jsfiddle.net/aerijman/t10powLm/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `label` is an inline element, you can't give it a size unless you change its display option to `block` or `inline-block`

```
 <label for="cars" style="display:block;">Choose a car:</label>
```

[MSDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Inline_elements) explaination.

Answer (score 0):

So far it worked this way:

*Style* should include `display: inline-block` and  `width: 10em;` and the `label tag` should **close** after the `select tag`.

```
<form action="/action_page.php">
  <label for="cars" style="display: inline-block; width: 10em;">Choose a car:
  <select name="cars" id="cars">
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="opel">Opel</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
  </select></label>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

See [here](https://jsfiddle.net/aerijman/t10powLm/8/)

I am still looking for a more thorough explanation to learn from!